# Telegram bot. Push users to use buttons if a user uses test message

Tags: python, telegram, chatbot

What should I use if the user didn't choose any button but he wrote a message, and I want to tell him that he has to click one of the buttons and show them again (IMPORTANT: from the previous step, because such steps can be a lot.)

```
import config
import telebot


permissions = config.permissions
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.API_BOT_TEST_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def test_message(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Алматы', callback_data='city_Алматы'))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нур-Султан', callback_data='city_Нур-Султан'))
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Choose your city', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: 'city' in call.data)
def query(call):
    bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Good choice!')
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.from_user.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, reply_markup='')

##### what should I use if the user didn't choose any button but he wrote a message, and I want to tell him that he has to click one of the buttons and show them again (IMPORTANT: from the previous step)?


bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need. Use `register_next_step_handler`

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def test_message(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Алматы', callback_data='city_Алматы'))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нур-Султан', callback_data='city_Нур-Султан'))
    msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Choose your city', reply_markup=markup)

    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_city_step)

def process_city_step(message):
    if not message.text.startswith('/'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'You has to click one of the buttons!')
    test_message(message)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: 'city' in call.data)
def query(call):
    bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Good choice!')
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.from_user.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, reply_markup='')

##### what should I use if the user didn't choose any button but he wrote a message, and I want to tell him that he has to click one of the buttons and show them again (IMPORTANT: from the previous step)?


bot.polling()
```